# How to enable the MySQL BINARY operator in Hibernate queries and Session.get()

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, orm

Is it possible to fetch the record using HQL against MySQL with a query like this?

```
 select * from students where binary sid='s001'
```

I am using hibernate 4.3 and this **BINARY** operator is not recognized by Hibernate. If I want to achieve the same with `Session.get()`, what do I have to do?

Comment: Still not clear what exactly is the problem, do you wish to run MySQL queries in hibernate

Comment: I want the equivalent functionality of BINARY keyword from MySQL in Hibernate, while writing any hql. And also the same task by Session.get(), but not want to do it manually in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both MySQL and HQL support the CAST() function so you can rewrite your query as:

```
select * 
from students 
where CAST(sid as binary) = CAST('s001' as binary)
```

For Session.get() you need to use the [@Loader](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/Loader.html) Hibernate custom annotation. You can find more on the [@Loader usage](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch13.html#querysql-cud) here.

Comment: I couldn't find a good document on @Loader in short time span. But looking at few example, I assume that it will fire a custom query to fetch data over id, when Session.get() will be used. And, that custom query will be linked via "namedQuery" in annotation. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I added some links to guide you with the @Loader annotation.

Comment: Yeah! That's what I was searching for. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: If I write HQL as "...CAST(stud.sid AS BINARY) = CAST('s001')", it is throwing null pointer exception since BINARY is not resolved as a type. Rather, "BINARY(stud.sid) = BINARY('s001')" works well. Does CAST need any special care to implement in this case?

Comment: You can register the BINARY function in a custom Hibernate Dialect that extends the MySQLDialect. This way you can use the BINARY function like any other HQL functions.

Comment: I didn't registered anything externally, but it worked. The reason may be this- registerColumnType( Types.BINARY, "binary($l)" ) as defined in MySQLDialect. So, bit confused, whether my code working as a function or a data type

Comment: That's for mapping a BINARY column to a byte []. That's what the register type does.